# Image resize not working in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-image, bitmapimage

I have 1024 x 900 image coming from server. And I want to get the half of this image.

I use this code

```
img.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()/2));
```

But when I do this I have this error

```
y+height must be <=bitmap.getHeight
```

What should I do here for not getting the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But with that values you can just get an unexpected part of the image, or more likely, an error.

if you check the [docs of the function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) you can see this signature:

```
createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

so, you have to indicate the x and y of the starting point, and the width and height of the rectangle you want.

if you want the top half, you use:

```
img.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth()  , bitmap.getHeight() / 2));
```

if you want the second half, you use:

```
img.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, bitmap.getWidth()  , bitmap.getHeight() / 2));
```

Comment: Thank you man for your help but I need second half of circle not the first half. I think you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The params should be the bitmap, the starting x and y, the width and the height. Then try:

```
img.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2));
```

Comment: I have to keep image width size, but height must be the half.

Comment: simply set bitmap.getWidth() in the 4th param